# closed form for $\psi^{(-2)}\left(\frac{1}{4} \right)$

Tags: integration, special-functions, closed-form, polygamma, catalans-constant

the polygamma function of negative order exist in a lot of complicated integrals like this integral:
$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{4}} x \psi(x) dx=\left(x \psi^{(-1)}(x) \right)^{\frac{1}{4}}_0-\int_0^{\frac{1}{4}} \psi^{(-1)}(x)dx=\frac{1}{4} \ln \Gamma{\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}-\psi^{(-2)}\left(\frac{1}{4} \right)  $$
now how can we prove the closed form
$$\psi^{(-2)}\left(\frac{1}{4} \right)=\frac{1}{8}\ln \left(2\pi A^9  \right)+\frac{C}{4\pi}$$
Where $A$ is Glaisher-Knkelin constant $C$ is Catalan's constant

Answer (score 4):

From [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042798001927#:%7E:text=Liouville%27s%20fractional%20integration%20is%20used,of%20the%20Hurwitz%20Zeta%20function.) we get that:
$$\psi^{(-2)}(z)=\frac{(1-z)z}{2}+\frac{z}{2}\log(2\pi)-\zeta'(-1)+\zeta'(-1,z)$$
Additionally we can [note that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function#Derivatives):
$$\zeta'(-1)=\frac1{12}-\ln(A)$$
As for the derivative of the incomplete zeta function, I have not found any "nice forms" for it yet but will keep searching

Comment: All you need to complete the evaluation is in : MILLER J., ADAMCHIK V.: [Derivatives of the Hurwitz Zeta function for rational arguments](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042798001939).
Here, at [2](19), they present the formula for the value of $\zeta'(-1,1/4)$.